# Python Stomp connection to ActiveMQ has wrong Topic Name

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm trying to form a Python + [Stomp](https://github.com/jasonrbriggs/stomp.py) subscription to an ActiveMQ server.  I'm testing against an ActiveMQ server on localhost.  It all seems to work OK, except the subscription name for Topic `XYZ` is being named `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Queue.XYZ`, and the queue I want to connect to (created by a java client) is named *only* `XYZ`.

Is there a way to get subscribed to this "short" name queue?

```
import stomp

QUEUE_NAME='XYZ'

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message)
    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        print('received a message "%s"' % message)

headers = {}
conn = stomp.Connection( )
conn.set_listener('127.0.0.1:61616', MyListener())
conn.start()
conn.connect('admin', 'admin', wait=True)

conn.subscribe(destination=QUEUE_NAME, id=2, ack='auto')

time.sleep(6660)
conn.disconnect()
```

The local ActiveMQ Console shows the "Topic":
[image: Screenshot of ActiveMQ Topics panel]

Whereas the real server has a short-named queue:
[image: Correct Name]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got back to this problem... After reading some other examples, I guessed at an answer, tested, and it worked (phew!).  Previously I could see my own messages, but the target subscriber (written in java) never received my messages.

If you want to send to an existing ActiveMQ queue with the current stomp library, the queue name needs to be prefixed with `/topic/`. For example (as per my question) if you want to send to the queue named `XYZ`, the stomp sending code needs to use a destination of `/topic/XYZ`.  *If this is documented somewhere, I could not find it!*

Obligatory code snippet:

```
import time
import stomp

MQ_SERVER     = "192.168.1.111"
MQ_PORT       = 61613
MQ_USERNAME   = "user"
MQ_PASSWORD   = "pass"
MQ_QUEUENAME  = 'XYZ'

conn = stomp.Connection( [( MQ_SERVER, MQ_PORT )] )
conn.start()
conn.connect( MQ_USERNAME, MQ_PASSWORD, wait=True )

for i in range( 3 ):
    conn.send( body="Hello World", destination='/topic/'+MQ_QUEUENAME )  # <- HERE
    time.sleep( 1 )

conn.disconnect()
```

I'm not sure if this is only for ActiveMQ, or for other message-system flavours.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like normal broker behavior in order to support "advisory messages". It shouldn't have any direct impact on your application. See the [ActiveMQ documentation on this subject](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) for more details.